# docker-compose [Error 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, django, docker-compose, docker-machine

I'm getting this error when running docker-compose,

```
python: can't open file 'manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

the script is:

```
docker-compose -f dev.yml run django python manage.py makemigrations
```

file **dev.yml**

```
version: '2'

volumes:
  postgres_data_dev: {}
  postgres_backup_dev: {}

services:
  postgres:
    build: ./compose/postgres
    volumes:
      - postgres_data_dev:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - postgres_backup_dev:/backups
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=backend

  django:
   build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/django/Dockerfile-dev
    command: python /app/manage.py runserver_plus 0.0.0.0:8000
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=backend
      - USE_DOCKER=yes
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    links:
      - postgres
```

I'm using: **docker-machine version 0.6.0, build e27fb87**

and
**docker-compose version 1.8.0, build f3628c7
docker-py version: 1.9.0
CPython version: 2.7.9
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013**

Have anyone get any idea??
Please help me to resolve it?
Thanks a lot

Comment: In `command:` you use `python /app/manage.py `, I think you need to use the path in the `run` as well. `/app/manage.py`

Comment: Any Update to this issue?